# Pass Array as parameter to Oracle stored proc from c# to bulk insert

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I am trying to send arrays as parameter to Oracle stored proc in order to process bulk insert.

```
type Licensingentity_id is table of odilic_admin.licensingentity.licensingentity_id%type index by pls_integer;
type Nationalprovidernumber is table of odilic_admin.licensingentity.nationalprovidernumber%type index by pls_integer;
type Home_state_province_id is table of odilic_admin.licensingentity.home_state_province_id%type index by pls_integer;

procedure HomeStateLookup_bulk_insert(i_entityId    in Licensingentity_id,
                                      i_npn         in Nationalprovidernumber,
                                      i_homeStateId in Home_state_province_id)     is
    v_caller varchar2(60) := 'System_Scheduler';
begin
    FORALL i IN 1 .. i_entityId.count
    insert into home_state_lookup_stg
      (licensingentity_id,
       npn,
       home_state_province_id,
       isprocessed,
       inserted_by,
       inserted_date,
       updated_by,
       updated_date)
    values
      (i_entityId(i),
       i_npn(i),
       i_homeStateId(i),
       0,
       v_caller,
       sysdate,
       v_caller,
       sysdate);

end HomeStateLookup_bulk_insert;
```

and here is the c# code

```
 NiprConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ODI.NIPR.DB.Reader"].ConnectionString;
        OracleConnection cnn = new OracleConnection(NiprConnectionString);
        cnn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = NaicStateLookupRepositoryProcedures.HOME_STATE_BULK_INSERT;
        cmd.BindByName = true;
        cmd.ArrayBindCount = entities.Count;

        var i_entityId = new OracleParameter();
        var i_npn = new OracleParameter();
        var i_homeStateId = new OracleParameter();

        i_entityId.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
        i_npn.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        i_homeStateId.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;

        i_entityId.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
        i_npn.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
        i_homeStateId.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;

        i_entityId.Value = entities.Select(c => c.Key).ToArray();
        i_npn.Value = entities.Select(c => c.Value.Item1).ToArray();
        i_homeStateId.Value = entities.Select(c => c.Value.Item2).ToArray();

        i_entityId.Size = entities.Count;
        i_npn.Size = entities.Count;
        i_homeStateId.Size = entities.Count;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(i_entityId);
        //cmd.Parameters[0].Value = i_entityId;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(i_npn);
        //cmd.Parameters[1].Value = i_npn;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(i_homeStateId);
        //cmd.Parameters[2].Value = i_homeStateId;
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but getting an exception -

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 52: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ">"
>   when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( ) - + case mod new not null

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't promise this is the answer, and I don't have the tables you reference to test this for myself, but at first glance I noticed you set:

```
cmd.BindByName = true;
```

As such, I think you need to declare your parameter names:

```
var i_entityId = new OracleParameter("i_entityId");
var i_npn = new OracleParameter("i_npn");
var i_homeStateId = new OracleParameter("i_homeStateId");
```

I've never passed an array as a parameter to a procedure, but if you were to do this with a normal insert, it would look something like this:

```
string sql = "insert into foo values (:boo, :bar, :baz)";

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("boo", OracleDbType.Varchar2));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("bar", OracleDbType.Date));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("baz", OracleDbType.Varchar2));

cmd.Parameters[0].Value = booArray;
cmd.Parameters[1].Value = barArray;
cmd.Parameters[2].Value = bazArray;

cmd.ArrayBindCount = booArray.Length;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I would start by defining the parameters with the parameter names, though.